# Why Mac Handoff shows the model of my iPhone so weirdly?

Tags: macos, dock, continuity

My Mac's dock has been showing the Handoff option very weirdly for around 6 months now (can't remember if it was already like this before Catalina). **Is this normal now, aka does this happen on everyone's Mac?** If not what should actually be on the text, and how to fix this?

[image: Dock Handoff]

Comment: Seems normal to me. The iPhone X is made in multiple models, each model with subtly different specifications and intended for different markets. Each of the alphanumerics is an iPhone X model.

Comment: Yes, but my mac surely knows the exact model and even the name of my iPhone, why no show that?

Comment: Presumably because that's how Apple wrote the software. And why Apple did something (or didn't do it, or didn't do it differently), is off-topic. You can read more about that on the Help page: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: That doesn't answer the part of my question that is this normal and does this happen on everyone's mac?

Comment: That is not normal. I use handoff quite a bit and have never seen it like that with all the model numbers. I’m assuming you’re on Catalina now?  It’s obviously not a mission critical issue” but if possible, install Mojave or earlier onto a USB flash (just for testing) and boot from that. This way, we can confirm if it is a Catalina issue or not and when done, just reboot from your regular drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not normal. Hard to say what the issue was, but after changing phones it's now showing a much less verbose text:

[image: handoff]